# Gnuplot "vector line"

Tags: vector, gnuplot, marker

I am trying to generate a plot which uses arrows as markers in Gnuplot. These arrows I want to turn in a specific angle which I know. So I have value triples of x1 ... xn, y1...yn, alpha1...alphan. Sorry, I wasn't able to include a pic from my hard drive to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Basically, for every (15th or so) x-y pair, the marker should be an arrow which uses a certain angle.

The measured data is tightly packed so I suppose I will have to define an increment between the markers. The length of the arrow can be the same all over.

I would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Added info: This question refers to Gnuplot

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot has a plot mode `with vectors` that is what you want

Given that your file has the following format, `x y angle` and assuming that
your angle is in radians, you have to take into account that

1. `with vectors` requires 4 parameters, namely `x y dx dy` where `dx`
     and `dy` are the  projections of the lenght  of the arrow.
2. this draws only the arrows, if you want a line you have to make 
     two passes on the data.
3. you want to draw an arrow for a data point over, say, 10 points.

That said, I'd proceed like this

```
dx(a) = 0.2*cos(a) # 0.2 is an arbitrary scaling factor
dy(a) = 0.2*sin(a)
# this draws the arrows
plot 'mydata.dat' every 10 using 1:2:(dx(a)):(dy(a)) with vectors
# this draws the line
plot 'mydata.dat'
```

You may want to use `help plot` to find the detailed explanation of all the parameters that you can apply to a `with vectors` plot.

Credits: [An article on the *gnuplotting* site](http://www.gnuplotting.org/vector-field-from-data-file/)

Comment: +1, depending on  the meaning of the angle one could need an additional `set size ratio -1` to have the same units on the x and y axis.